# Do gods and goddesses know all languages?

Tags: gods, goddess, language

Is it true that gods and goddesses know all languages? If true, where it has been mentioned?

Comment: Do you mean Devi Devatas of Swarga Loka by gods and Goddesses?

Comment: Yeah @The Destroyer

Comment: This does not seem to be reasonable question.. How do you get such strange questions? How is it useful?

Comment: To know how they use to communicate with people on earth who knows only their native language.. @Praphullla Koushik

Comment: I believe language is never a way to communicate... Suppose you know how they communicate what do you get from that? @hanugm

Comment: What's so much strange in it? Many people say their sad, happiness, prayer etc., to gods and goddesses In their native languages before idols. So, I asked whether they know all the existing languages on earth or not  @Praphulla Koushik

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If I know how they communicate, I can try to communicate in such a way.

Comment: One thing is for sure. The Vaidik and Tantric Deva Devatas understand Deva Vaani Sanskrit. It's not a co-incidence that Sanskrit has been found to be the best language for Computers.